# Displaying BCS data like profile view

Tags: bcs

I have configured external content type and able to display the data in Business data list web part.

But now it is showing in table format.

Emp ID  Emp Name
1   aaa
2   bbb

but I want something like profile view

Emp ID :1

Emp Name : aaa

Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think about two possible solutions:

1. Create a custom webpart that will display the data in the way you want it to be displayed (data from external list you may easily retrieve using REST API)
2. Edit your webpart. When you open the page with webpart -> click Edit WebPart and in the Data View Properties you can edit XSL file that defines the way data is being displayed. You may do the same from SharePoint Designer - but I didn't try this.